# Run ajax calls in order

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I have a dynamically determined list of ajax calls that need to be made one after the other. Since promises aren't implemented equally in all browsers, is there a way to make each ajax call after the previous was completed?

I have tried:

```
var favoritesArray = [1,2,3] //dynamically created by user
var arrayOfCalls = $.each(favoritesArray, function each(idx) {
  var favId = favoritesArray[idx];
  return $.ajax({ url: '/favorites/' + favId, type: 'DELETE' });
});
$.when(arrayOfCalls)
.then(function success() {
  doStuff();
});
```

All the calls run, but don't wait for the previous one to finish. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Not sure why you are worried about it. None of these appear to be dependent on the previous ones. `$.when` will be consistent cross browser but note that nothing gets returned from `$.each` so `arrayOfCalls ` will be undefined

Comment: Each call updates the same list and if the calls are fired off simultaneously, the items remaining in the list will be incorrect and different, depending on which completed first.

Comment: Thanks for the note about $.each though.

Comment: `arrayOfCalls.reduce((p, c) => p.then(c), $.when()).then(function success() { ...`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that looks like it should do it, but doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of recursion. (i used setTimeout in place of AJAX request)

```
function syncExecute(index,length){
 var favId = favoritesArray[index];
 setTimeout(function(){
if(index<length){
      syncExecute(index+1,length);
            console.log(index);
      }else{
      console.log("All Call Executed");
      }
},5000);

}

syncExecute(0,favoritesArray.length);
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/b18vo9ds/

You can replace setTimeout with AJAX request, and resursive call the function on success of AJAX request.